# UISearchBar displays in the root view but not in any other view on the tab bar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, xib

I have implemented the search bar for the table in the first tab and this works fine and filters fine, however, with the same code and the xib linked up all the same etc on the second tab it no longer displays the search bar. Is there a simple reason to this?

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the UISearchBar into its own class and then call it from the multiple views.  It is not meant to be reinstantiated for each view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple reason—the search bar is a subview of your main view, so when that view gets swiped off screen, it disappears with that view. To fix this, you'll have to add the search bar to the view that holds your tab bar controller—you'll probably have to put it in MainWindow.xib. You can still connect it to your tab bar controller if you need to—just add a reference to in the XIB.